# How to click on button with text Show more results using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

For this button:
[image]

I used these pieces of code, but it did not work.

```
WebDriverWait(wd, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(., 'Show more results')]"))).click()
```

and

```
button = wd.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'My Button')]")
button.click()
```

Comment: Confirm the URL please.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=aircraft+fuselage+airplane+fly+aviation+aircraft+wing+aerodynamic+plane+aircraft&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS985US986&sxsrf=ALiCzsbctupnUvetvOBSuPGjv8vRok0SQg:1658425706014&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiY896YxYr5AhXXpokEHRjuCkEQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=552&bih=679&dpr=1.25

Comment: Did you also figure out the scrolling, and reaching the end of page?

Comment: yes I did it with wd.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')

Comment: That will only scroll the page once. At that point, G Images will load a new set, and you need to scroll it a couple of times as well. How did you account for it?

Comment: Someone made an answer here but deleted the answer I got this from him or her. wd.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;") this seems to be useful.

Comment: And how many images did you find in total, for that particular search? Just curious.

Comment: with some conditions, I got 115.

Comment: There are over 700 images returned by that specific google image search: https://www.google.com/search?q=aircraft+fuselage+airplane+fly+aviation+aircraft+wing+aerodynamic+plane+aircraft&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS985US986&sxsrf=ALiCzsbctupnUvetvOBSuPGjv8vRok0SQg:1658425706014&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiY896YxYr5AhXXpokEHRjuCkEQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=552&bih=679&dpr=1.25

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to understand: is your code retrieving all of them, clicking the 'load more' button as may times as it appears, and stops when the page says 'Look like you've reach the end' or something like that?

Comment: As I said I used some conditions. since I wanted to get the image URL there were some restrictions, for example, I did not want images from Wikipedia and so on.

Comment: It's not about that
: I'm curious if you managed to click that button as many times as it appeared, scrolled the page as many times as needed to load all of them (dependant on your window size, it can be 4-5 times or more), then stopped once there were no more images?

Comment: I will then assume you have not. Thank you.

Comment: so sorry for the late response. That's true I could not find any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. *`Show more results`* isn't the `innerText` but the value of the `value` attribute.

---

### Solution

To click on the element with text as ***Show more results*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value='Show more results']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Show more results']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```